# A code for step by step JPEG compression

Tags: image, jpeg, emgucv, steganography, image-conversion

The JPEG compression steps are as follows:

**Raw image data** -> forward DCT -> Quantization -> Entropy encoding -> **JPEG image**

There are numbers of converters and APIs out there and the converting process is a single API call. I was unable to find a step by step code. My question is where can I find a code for each individual step, or can I perform these individual steps one by one and produce a standard JPEG image? I am using EmguCV for my image steganography project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where can I find a code for each individual step

If a C library might be a candidate for you, you should have a look at [jpec](https://github.com/Moodstocks/jpec) a lightweight JPEG encoder written in C - note that it only supports grayscale images.

The main encoding function ([`jpec_enc_run`](https://github.com/Moodstocks/jpec/blob/21e07e6d1f27f0e4214d4a062aa8ef06415bfb6b/src/enc.c#L76)) is easy to read and provides each above step via internal functions:

```
/* open = write JPEG headers */
jpec_enc_open(e);

while (jpec_enc_next_block(e)) {
  /* compute the DCT for the current 8x8 block */
  jpec_enc_block_dct(e);

  /* quantize the DCT coefficients for the current block */
  jpec_enc_block_quant(e);

  /* re-order the quantized coefficients with the zig-zag pattern */
  jpec_enc_block_zz(e);

  /* perform entropy coding of the current block and write to the global buffer*/
  e->hskel->encode_block(e->hskel->opq, &e->block, e->buf);
}

/* close = write JPEG end of image marker */
jpec_enc_close(e);
```

> can I perform these individual steps one by one and produce a standard JPEG image

This is not available out-of-the box with jpec, but you should be able to modify it for that purpose quite easily (by exposing and/or adapting the low-level internal functions).